# Getting address from gdb.Value

Tags: python, gdb

I'm creating a command for gdb using python integration and trying to get the address of a variable. I've got the value already using:

```
v = gdb.parse_and_eval("var_name")
```

But that `v` can serialise in a number of ways depending on the type. For example if it's a `char*`, it will be displayed as:

```
>>> print v
0x7f06a2cfd320 "x"
>>> print v.address
None
```

Ok, so this doesn't work as expected. I tried first dereferencing, then getting the address, but that gives me back the original value:

```
>>> print v.dereference().address
0x7f06a2cfd320 "x"
```

How can I get the address part only? The only way I could find so far looks a bit long:

```
>>> vptr = gdb.lookup_type("void").pointer()
>>> print v.cast(vptr)
0x7f06a2cfd320
```

Is there some more direct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't totally clear to me what you are asking.

In the first part it sounds like you want the address of the variable "var_name".  In this case, you want ".address" as you wrote; however, note that not all variables have addresses.  For example the variable could be put into a register by the compiler.  Given that this attribute's value is None, I would guess this is what happened.  (You can use other gdb commands to find out for sure...)

In the second part, though, it sounds like maybe you want the value of the pointer.  You can either just use the value directly (things like + work fine on Value); or you can cast it directly to a Python "long" to get the value as a plain old scalar:

```
number = long(v)
```